# Imágenes embebidas como adjuntas al enviar email a un correo gmail con PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Buenos días.

Tal como lo he puesto en el título, en mi código tengo una funcionalidad para enviar correos con PHPMailer.

El problema que presenta es que, a pesar de que en correos outlook la imagen se muestra embebida correctamente, en gmail no ocurre así, en este caso se muestran después del cuerpo del correo como archivos adjuntos y no embebido como debería ser

El código para el envío del mail con PHPMailer es algo como esto:

```php
<?php 
$body = "<p>
             Texto 
        </p>
        <br/><br/>".$pie_pagina."";

$pie_pagina = "<img src='cid:imgmail.jpg' border='0'/>";

$mail = new Phpmailer();                                        

            $mail->PluginDir = PHPMAILER;                       
            $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
            $mail->Host = HOST;
            $mail->Port = PUERTO;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = USUARIO;
            $mail->Password = PASSWORD;
            $mail->From = "ejemplo@ejemplo.com";
            $mail->FromName = "Eemplo";
            $mail->AddAddress('ejemplo@gmail.com');
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../../img/imgmail.jpg', '../../img/imgmail.jpg');
            $mail->Subject = "Asunto";                      
            $mail->Body = $body;                                            
            $mail->AltBody = "Texto Altbody ";                      
            $mail->IsHtml(true);
            $mail->AddAttachment(@$filename);
            $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";                                       
            $mail->Send(); 
?>
```

Como ya mencioné funciona bien en outlook, pero en gmail no está embebida la imagen, sino que se ve como un archivo adjunto.

Si alguien sabe cual podría ser la causa y si hay alguna posible solución, apreciaría mucho la ayuda. He intentado varias soluciones y hasta ahora no me ha funcionado. Intenté insertarla directamente en el body sin el cid y tampoco funcionó.

Agradecido de antemano, quedo a la espera de sus respuestas.

Comment: Diria que estas usando mal el método `AddEmbeddedImage`, ya que no estás indicando correctamente el `cid`. Intenta hacerlo así `$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("../../img/imgmail.jpg", "imgmail.jpg", "imgmail.jpg", "base64", "image/jpg");`

Comment: He probado lo que me has indicado en el comentario, sin embargo sigue sin mostrar la imagen embebida

Comment: Intenta sacando el `.jpg` del `cid`, tanto en el `HTML` y en el `AddEmbeddedImage` (_segundo parámetro_)

Comment: Otra cosa, `$pie_pagina` debería estar definida antes que `$body`

Comment: Vale. He definido `$pie_pagina` antes que `$body` y quitado el `.jpg`. Sigue igual

Comment: Si con la configuración tal cual la muestras se envían los emails, con los cambios que ha indicado @Marcos debería funcionar.

Comment: Hola. Ahora es que estaba revisando. Bueno, el mail si que se envía y va bien, pero cuando es a gmail la imagen sigue sin aparecer embebida sino como archivo adjunto. Estaba revisándolo con un compañero y creemos que puede ser la configuración del servidor de correos.